# カラムを結合した場合のインデックスの効果

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, database, oracle

インデックスが
COL_A
COL_B
COL_C
の列で作成されている時、

```
WHERE
  COL_A || COL_B || COL_C = 'ABC'
```

のような検索条件はインデックスが有効利用されるでしょうか。
また、

```
ORDER BY
  COL_A || COL_B || COL_C ASC
```

のような並び替えの場合はどうでしょうか。
インデックスの効果があるかどうかはRDBによって異なるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

検証したわけではないですが、 No だと思います。

というのも、例えば mysql データベースでは、それぞれの select を実行する時に、各読み込む必要があるテーブルに対してどのインデックスでアクセスしたらいいかを決定して、その通りに InnoDB から読むというような動作をします。(そして where 条件に合致しないものを片っ端から落としていく)その時に複数方法でのインデックスアクセスを許容するような構造をしていないと思っていて、 explain などのフォーマット的にも、多分そのようなことは無理なのではないかと思っています。